# Is there a way to make Celery/RabbitMQ persistent?

Tags: database, persistence, queue, rabbitmq, celery

So that if my server crashes, I still have my Tasks?

Answer (score 20):

RabbitMQ can be persistent, and Celery sends persistent messages by default, so you don't have to do anything to enable this.

Comment: Specifically, use the 'durable' setting in RabbitMQ.

Comment: durable actually only flags so that the queues and exchanges are restored when the broker is restarted.  To send persistent messages you need to set `basic_publish(..., delivery_mode=2)`

Comment: @asksol how can I do this with Redis??

Comment: @asksol to clarify, we're saying that all messages are sent with `delivery_mode=2` by celery? Does celery create the default `celery` queue with durable flag? What if we choose use a different queue, will it be created with `durable` implicitly or we need to make sure to flag it manually?

Answer (score 0):

rabbitmq persist those messages by default

rabbitmq wont delete messages if they are not acknowledged by consumers,so that's how celery does.

when worker crashed and restarted again,they will receive the messages that not acknowledged last time before crashed.